# Why is my Total_Pay Column not correct in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, left-join

I'm new to SQL and looking to understand why my query is not pulling back the correct Total_Pay. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.   I'm assuming that its due to a mistake in the Join segment.  It's a fairly long query so I'll try and just provide the basics:

```
SELECT
    payee.name as Carrier_Name,
    payee.ID,
    count(DISTINCT drs_settle_hist.order_id) as Order_Count,
    sum(DISTINCT drs_settle_hist.total_pay) as Total_Pay,
FROM movement
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        payee ON movement.override_payee_id = payee.id
    AND
        movement.company_id = payee.company_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN movement_order ON
        movement_order.movement_id = movement.id
    AND
        movement_order.company_id = movement.company_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON
        movement_order.order_id = orders.id
    AND movement_order.company_id = orders.company_id
    JOIN
        stop on orders.id = stop.order_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cargo_claim ON
        cargo_claim.order_id = orders.id
    Left outer JOIN settlement ON
        settlement.movement_id = movement.ID
    LEFT JOIN order_post_hist ON
        order_post_hist.order_id = orders.id
    AND
        cargo_claim.carrier_id = payee.id
    JOIN drs_settle_hist ON
        drs_settle_hist.order_id = orders.id
WHERE
    payee.company_id = 'TMS3'
AND
    drs_settle_hist.pay_date BETWEEN '2023-01-01' AND '2023-01-31'`
```

Any advice you can provide it appreciated.  If you need additional information, let me know.
Thank you!

It appears that the total pay number was doubling incorrectly so I tried adding "Distinct" to the total pay query.  That changed the total pay number but its still not correct. For example, the total pay for this vendor should be $248,000 but, in the query results its showing as $74,000

Comment: Are there any duplicates with `Total_Pay` value ?

Comment: You have to identify which join doubles your stuff, and either remove it or rewrite your query. SUM DISTINCT is not the way to go, since you will remove duplicate payments which are legitimate

Comment: Aggregate in subqueries before joining.

Comment: There are no duplicates with Total_pay

Comment: How do I aggregate in subqueries before joining?

Comment: @Polly15562, something like: select * from tablea inner join tableb on tableb.id = tablea.id inner join (select sum(amount) as sumAmount, id from tablec group by id) c ON c.id = b.id

Comment: `sum(DISTINCT` is just weird there is rarely a reason to use it. It looks like you are joining tables which are causing the result to multiply out. Aggregate them in subqueries before joining. Without seeing your table definitions (including PK/FK) it's hard to say.

Comment: Ok thanks, doing research now on how to subquery lol as I'm just beginning.

Comment: I agree with @Charlieface. it is likely you have multiple independent one-to-many joins that are causing unwanted data duplication. Using `DISTINCT` is rarely a good fix for this.  Looking at your query, the `cargo_claim`, `settlement`, and `order_post_hist` appear unused. Eliminating those may help. The `stop` table is also unused, except for the fact that the join effectively adds an exists condition. I suggest you drop these table references and remove the DISTINCT from the Total_Pay calkculation. If you still have issues, select and examine the raw data without the group by.